# How was Isaac conceived?

Tags: genesis

How was Isaac conceived? Did Abraham have sex with Sarah or was it just by God's divine power without Abraham's involvement?

Comment: Hi Leslie, welcome to the community and thanks for asking a question! However, here on BH.SE, we like to analyze passages for their context and wording. Could you provide a passage that we can analyze to come to a conclusion? Thanks!

Comment: The situation is absolutely clear from Hebrews 11:12 _Therefore sprang there even of one, and him as good as dead, so many as the stars of the sky in multitude, and as the sand which is by the sea shore innumerable._ Isaac sprang from Abraham.

Comment: Genesis chapter 18 v 10 and Genesis 21 v 1-2, even in the book of Hebrews 11 when it comes to the question of Issacs conception it refers to Sarah's faith not Abrahams in that respect

Comment: The correct English phrasal verb is "lie with".

Answer (score 2):

Gen 18 provides some facts that are undisputed.  v11 and v12 essentially say that Sarah had reached menopause.  While Abraham was old, that did not mean he was impotent; indeed, a few years' later he took another wife, Keturah, who bore several children to Abraham (Gen 25:1-4).

Therefore, while Sarah was infertile, both before her menopause and also because of her menopause, she was still a very beautiful woman (see Gen 20).  None of this meant that Abraham and Sarah had stopped coitus.

There is nothing here to suggest that Isaac's conception was immaculate.  In all probability, it occurred quite naturally; the miracle of God was the fertilisation.

Comment: I accept that the seed was from Abraham, but the conception itself appears to have been miraculous, the bible tells us a bit about the time Sarah Conceived but does not mention that Abraham was physically involved, when it came to Hagar the scriptures tell us Abraham went in to her Genesis 16 v4 but there is no such reference in relation to Sarah of have  missed something?

Comment: Let's not forget, however, that the apostle Paul tells us in Romans Chapter 4 that Abraham, "Without becoming weak in faith . . . contemplated his own body, now as good as dead since he was about a hundred years old, and the deadness of Sarah’s womb (v.19, NASB). Call the locution "as good as dead" as a euphemism, if you like, since there are many of them in Scriptures. If I'm not mistaken, then, Abraham considered himself unable to "know" his wife Sarah (i.e., he was, at age 100, impotent) & considered Sarah's womb to be "dead." God restored miraculously both Abe's potency & Sarah's fertility

Comment: Good comment.  You may well be correct.  We also know that Isaac was the promised child despite Abraham's efforts to have children by other means But God rejected them because they did not come from Abraham.

Comment: "Immaculate conception" is not the same as "virgin birth".

Comment: That is true but irrelevant - I did not equate the two.  Sarah was obviously not a virgin.

Answer (score 1):

A year ago I wrote a somewhat lengthy article on this subject, which I paste below.

Professor Daniel Boyarin in a book published in 1994 [1] and Rabbi Samuel Z. Glaser in a recent article [2] have interpreted the contrasting descriptions of the conceptions [3] of Ishmael and Isaac in Paul's letter to the Galatians:

- "according to the flesh" versus "through the promise" (Gal 4:23)
- "according to the flesh" versus "according to the Spirit" (Gal 4:29)

as meaning that, while Ishmael's conception was exclusively through natural physical means, Isaac's conception was exclusively through a miraculous divine intervention without any physical cooperation by Abraham. Naming this interpretation EMC (exclusively miraculous conception) and the traditional interpretation that Isaac was conceived through a conjugal act of Abraham and Sarah, who were for that purpose miraculously assisted by God, the first regarding potency and the second regarding fertility, CMC (cooperative miraculous conception), I argue below that:

1. Considering only these passages and Gen 15:4, CMC is far more plausible than EMC.
2. Adding to the above Rom 4:18-19, which deals with the main subject of the letter to the Galatians, CMC is the only possible interpretation.
3. Adding Gal 5:19-21, CMC makes even more sense.

---

1. Isaac's conception "through the promise" means that he was conceived in fulfillment of the promise made by God to Abraham, which was twofold:

   - 1st, about the "what": that Abraham's heir would be "one who will come forth from your own body" (Gen 15:4);
   - 2nd, about the "when": 'I will certainly return unto you when the season comes round; and, lo, Sarah your wife shall have a son.' (Gen 18:10).

Clearly the 1st promise necessarily implied that Isaac's conception - though miraculous because of the ages of Abraham and, above all, of Sarah - would take place through Abraham's physical cooperation, since otherwise Isaac would not be "one who will come forth from" Abraham's "own body".

Now, is it reasonable to posit that Paul did not have in mind the 1st promise of Gen 15:4 when writing the letter to the Galatians, but only the 2nd promise about the "when"? I argue that it is not: even when one may not agree with Paul's interpretation of Abraham's story, it is clear that he knows the subject. Anyway, the second part of my argument reinforces this point.

2. In a chapter of the letter to the Romans that deals with the same subject of the letter to the Galatians, namely justification by faith and not by the Law, Paul writes:

> In hope against hope he believed, so that he might become a father of
>   many nations according to that which had been spoken, “so shall your
>   descendants be.” Without becoming weak in faith he contemplated his
>   own body, now as good as dead since he was about a hundred years old,
>   and the deadness of Sarah’s womb; yet, with respect to the promise of
>   God, he did not waver in unbelief but grew strong in faith, giving
>   glory to God, and being fully assured that what God had promised, He
>   was able also to perform. (Rom 4:18-21)

If Isaac was to be conceived without Abraham's physical cooperation with Sarah, the lack of performative capacity of "his own body, now as good as dead since he was about a hundred years old," would have been wholly irrelevant to the purpose of Isaac's conception, as only "the deadness of Sarah’s womb" would have mattered. Thus, the fact that Paul praises Abraham's unwavering faith in God's promise in the face of his awareness of both facts (i.e. Abraham's lack of performative capacity and Sarah's barrennes) implies that, for Paul, God's promise was going to be fulfilled through Abraham's physical cooperation.

3. Let us note that, in the letter to the Galatians, there are two senses of "flesh" in which it appears in opposition with "Spirit":

a. the physical human body, in a passage alluding to the circumcission (Gal 3:3), 
b. the wrong tendencies of fallen human nature (Gal 5:13-25), a meaning which is particularly evident in this passage...

> Now the deeds of the flesh are evident, which are: sexual immorality,
>   impurity, sensuality, idolatry, sorcery, enmities, strife, jealousy,
>   outbursts of anger, disputes, dissensions, factions, envying,
>   drunkenness, carousing, and things like these, of which I forewarn
>   you, just as I have forewarned you, that those who practice such
>   things will not inherit the kingdom of God. (Gal 5:19-21)

... since "enmities, [...] disputes, dissensions, factions, envying" are not related to any inclination of the physical human body like e.g. sexual immorality is related to the sexual instinct.

Between these passages opposing "flesh" and "Spirit" in which "flesh" has only one of its two meanings, there are the closely paralell passages of 4:23 and:

> But just as at that time the one having been conceived according to
>   the flesh was persecuting the one [conceived] according to the Spirit,
>   so also it is now. (Gal 4:29)

Thus, whereas with "flesh" in the first meaning the statements in 4:23 and 4:29 that Ishmael was conceived "according to the flesh" mean that Ishmael was conceived through a physical sexual relation, with "flesh" in the second meaning the statements mean that Ishmael was conceived as a result of following a wrong tendency of fallen human nature. What was the specific wrong tendency in this case? Lack of trust in God.

God had promised Abraham that his heir would be "one who will come forth from your own body" (Gen 15:4). Therefore Abraham and Sarah could and should be absolutely sure that God would fulfill that promise at the time He considered right - a time which was known only by God -, and that at that time God would tell them what they should do to cooperate to the fulfillment of the promise. But as time passed and God did not reveal how his promise was going to be fulfilled, and as it could not be fulfilled through purely natural means by Abraham and Sarah since she was post-menopausal, Sarah felt that they should do something to make it happen, and came up with the idea of Abraham impregnating Hagar. Why was that idea "according to the flesh"? Because if God promises you that He will make something happen, you must just trust his word and not get impatient! At the right time - which only God knows - God will tell you what you should do to cooperate to the fulfillment of the promise. Until then, as far as the fulfillment of the promise is concerned, just trust, sit back and relax.

**References**

[1] Daniel Boyarin, "A Radical Jew: Paul and the Politics of Identity", University of California Press, Oct 14, 1994.
https://books.google.com/books?id=26hXerwRz5IC

[2] Samuel Z. Glaser (Oct 31, 2017). "Isaac’s Divine Conception?".
http://thetorah.com/isaacs-divine-conception/

[3] While only a few Bible translations have "conceived" instead of "born" in Gal 4:23 and 4:29, the verb gennaó means both "I beget" (of the male) and "I bring forth, give birth to" (of the female).

https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Galatians%204:23

http://biblehub.com/greek/1080.htm